# IDependencyResolver and ResolveFieldContext cannot be resolved while using latest GraphQL library in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

I am working on a project where I need to use `GraphQL` in my `asp.net core` 3.1 project and this is the first time I am working with `GraphQL`. I added all the required dependencies and when I try to build, it gives compilation error as follows:

```
PKIUYTSWS123:example-orders andy$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.1+52cd83677 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
Schema/OrdersSchema.cs(11,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDependencyResolver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/andy/Documents/work/git/example-orders/Orders/Orders.csproj]
Schema/OrdersSubscription.cs(34,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResolveFieldContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/andy/Documents/work/git/example-orders/Orders/Orders.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Schema/OrdersSchema.cs(11,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDependencyResolver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/andy/Documents/work/git/example-orders/Orders/Orders.csproj]
Schema/OrdersSubscription.cs(34,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResolveFieldContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/andy/Documents/work/git/example-orders/Orders/Orders.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

It looks like `IDependencyResolver` was removed in `GraphQL.NET 3.0` and I am not sure on how can I fix this issue in my project. This is all the dependencies I have here -

**Orders.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Types\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Types\**" />
    <None Remove="Types\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="3.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive.Compatibility" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Server.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.WebSockets" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.GraphiQL" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Voyager" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Orders\Orders.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is my [OrdersSubscription.cs](https://github.com/TechGeeky/example-orders/blob/master/Orders/Schema/OrdersSubscription.cs) class and [OrdersSchema.cs](https://github.com/TechGeeky/example-orders/blob/master/Orders/Schema/OrdersSchema.cs) class.

I have put together an example here in this [git repo](https://github.com/TechGeeky/example-orders) which outlines this problem. Any thoughts why I am getting this error and how can I fix it? Any help will be appreciate in fixing this issue in my git repo.

I am gonna run this code in production so trying to figure out the right and efficient way to integrate GraphQL in asp.net core 3.1 project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better use examples from this [repo](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/tree/master/src/AspNetCore) because it's up to date.

But to provide you info on what has changed:

1. There is no more `IDependencyResolver`, `IServiceProvider` used instead. You should pass it to base constructor instead of setting it directly to `DependencyResolver`.
2. Your mutations have code like this

   ```
   return await context.TryAsyncResolve(
       async c => await orders.CloseAsync(orderId));
   ```

   Not sure what is `TryAsyncResolve` but you should just call

   ```
   return await orders.CloseAsync(orderId));
   ```
3. You should use interfaces `IResolveEventStreamContext` and `IResolveFieldContext` instead of `ResolveEventStreamContext` and `ResolveFieldContext` classes.
4. You should install `GraphQL.SystemTextJson` or `GraphQL.NewtonsoftJson` and use chosen implementation.
5. You should provide `UserContext`.

Check sample projects and [documentation](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/introduction) for more info.

Comment: Let me check out the links you shared but just curious how can I fix this [line](https://github.com/TechGeeky/example-orders/blob/master/Orders/Schema/OrdersQuery.cs#L25) in my repo similar to examples you mentioned in pt2?

Comment: `resolve: async context =>  await orders.GetOrderByIdAsync(context .GetArgument<String>("orderId"))`

Comment: You mean like this `resolve: async context => {
                    return await orders.GetOrderByIdAsync(context .GetArgument<String>("orderId"));
                }`. It is giving compile error which I think is obvious mistake.

Comment: No. I mean what I say. The only obvious mistake here is a white space between `context` and `.GetArgument<String>`. This syntax called `expression body`, your syntax called `lambda expression`. And don't forget to add `using GraphQL;` for `GetArgument` extension method.